# It gives me an error at GPS

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gps, location

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this? It's giving me an error on ;}}
I added and removed {} and () but it didn't work.
I took this code from stackoverflow but it didn't work

```
   package com.f.da;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

    public class PageSeven extends Activity {
        Button da;   
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.oulo);
            addListenerOnButton();
        }
        public void addListenerOnButton() {
        da = (Button) findViewById(R.id.da);;
            da.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    String CURRENT_LOCATION = "37.980442, 23.727892";
                    String DESTINATION_LOCATION = "DA";
                    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+ CURRENT_LOCATION +" daddr="+DESTINATION_LOCATION));
                    startActivity(intent); 
                }
            }}; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: post stacktrace of the error...

Comment: umm, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `}};` with `});`. You need a closing `)` for the `setOnClickListener(`.